# C sockets upload and download a file in same request

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to receive a file thats uploaded by the client and in the same socket descriptor send a command download a file from the server in chunks

The issue is if the socket descriptors are in different files things work flawlessly but if its the same file client and server programs are hanging up

The second problem is even if its in different files I could not send the client a message saying that the file is received

Can anyone please advice

PS- to run the program might need to create a file named fileclient.txt and enter some random text

server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PORT 8088

int main(void){   
    int fd =0, confd = 0,b,tot;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

    char buff[1025];
    fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    printf("Socket created\n");

    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
    memset(buff, '0', sizeof(buff));

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    listen(fd, 10);

    while(1){
        confd = accept(fd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL);
        if (confd==-1) {
            perror("Accept");
            continue;
        }

        //READ COMMAND reads first 4 characters of the buffer
        int bf = recv(confd, buff, 1024,0);
        char *filecmd = malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
        memcpy(filecmd, buff, 4);
        filecmd[4] = 0; //string termination 

        //if command is DOWN send chunks to the client 
        if(strcmp(filecmd, "DOWN") == 0){
            int bt;
            char sendbuffer[100];
            FILE *fpdl = fopen("file.txt", "rb");
            if(fpdl == NULL){
                perror("File");
                return 2;
            }
            while( (bt = fread(sendbuffer, 1, sizeof(sendbuffer), fpdl))>0 ){
                send(confd, sendbuffer, bt, 0);
            }
            fclose(fpdl);
        }
        //if DOWN did not match that means client is uploading a file write down the file on server
        else{           
            FILE* fp = fopen( "newfile.txt", "wb");
            tot=0;
            tot+=bf;
            fwrite(buff, 1, bf, fp);

            if(fp != NULL){
                while( (b = recv(confd, buff, 1024,0))> 0 ) {                   
                    tot+=b;
                    fwrite(buff, 1, b, fp);
                }
                printf("Received byte: %d\n",tot);
                if (b<0) perror("Receiving Error");
                fclose(fp);

            } else {
                perror("File");
            }
        }
        free(filecmd);
        close(confd);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

client.c

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 8088


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int sfd =0, n=0, b;
    char sendbuffer[100];

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    sfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    b=connect(sfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    if (b==-1) {
        perror("Connect");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *fp = fopen("fileclient.txt", "rb");
    if(fp == NULL){
        perror("File");
        return 2;
    }

    while( (b = fread(sendbuffer, 1, sizeof(sendbuffer), fp))>0 ){
        send(sfd, sendbuffer, b, 0);
    }
    fclose(fp);


    char *rpccommand = "DOWN"; 
    send(sfd , rpccommand , strlen(rpccommand) , 0 ); 

    char buffer[1024] = {0}; 
    FILE* fpx = fopen( "downloadfile.txt", "wb");
    int tot=0, bn;
    if(fpx != NULL){
        while( (bn = recv(sfd, buffer, 1024,0))> 0 ) {
            tot+=bn;
            fwrite(buffer, 1, bn, fpx);
        }
        printf("Received byte: %d\n",tot);
        if (bn<0) perror("Receiving");
        fclose(fpx);
    } else {
        perror("File");
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: This seems like a good time to learn how to use a debugger to step through your programs statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: Are you aware that TCP is a stream protocol without datagrams? How does the server know when the whole file has been received?

Comment: `int bf = recv(confd, buff, 1024,0);` bf can now be -1,0,1..1024. What will your program do if bf is only `1`?

Comment: Any feedback here?

Comment: @Gerhardh  Sorry about the late response I deserve ! that, Terminate the connection once all sent on the client

BTW the idea is only to send commands limiting commands to 4 chars I mean "DOWN" is sent as data nothing more no data will be added after string "DOWN"

Comment: Don't you send a file to the server and also a "DOWN" command (or maybe multiple DOWN commands) to trigger download on same socket?

Comment: The idea is to have a que and send commands one by one,, I might need to switch to datagrams UDP isnt it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to expect that the string "DOWN" is recognized by the server and a download is triggered. This is very unlikely to happen.

TCP connections do not take care about granularity of data that is put into the socket. If you put in 1000 bytes at once on one side, it is not guaranteed that those 1000 bytes are received in one go.
You may receive either 1000 bytes or 500 + 500 bytes of 999 + 1 bytes.

Same applies if you send with multiple requests. Putting in 1000+4 bytes could result in receiving 1000+4 or 1004 or 500+500+4 bytes or any other combination.

This means that you cannot simply rely on receiving all bytes for the file upload first and then wait for another command ("DOWN") or another file. It is very likely that you will receive the "DOWN" together with the last bytes of the uploaded file and simply store them into the output file.

The same applies for download direction. The client would not be able to distinguish a file download from an "upload done" notification.

To solve your problem you need to introduce more logic into your protocol. There are various options:

- Use 1 socket and 1 connection for each operation or each direction. No need to mix everything into a single socket.
- Add some indication about file upload, e.g. total length to be expected in front of your upload.
- Use 1 socket for control flow and multiple others for data transfer (see FTP for details)